# QGIS 3 is there a way to calculate the merging of vector lines

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.6.2, I have a vector layer with thousands of vector lines on it. I don't know if this is possible but I want to see if these vector lines merge at all. To be more specific I have trails that I want to see if they merge to one or few points to cross roads. Is there a plugin I can use or a method to find this out?

Answer (score 2):

you can make a vector grid (Vector-> Create Grid), e.g. 100 or 50 meters and then to count the lines per cell with the processing tool "Sum Line length" which also counts the lines per cell.

[image]

Comment: Well done, this is an excellent answer. I have a small suggestion to improve the efficiency of this analysis (which might be slow if you have a lot of grid cells). First use `select by location` to select the grid cells that intersect trail lines. Run the `sum line length` tool on selected features only.